# Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied

Tags: php, mysqli

I noticed this has been asked several times, but I can't find an answer that works. I'm writing a class to handle my database calls, and for some reason can't establish a connection.

This is the error I received:

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in...

This is the code that attempts to create an instance of the class:

```
    <?php
    require_once 'inventoryconfig.php';
    require("MySQLiClass.inc");
    ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);

    echo "control";

    /* works */
    $connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database, $db_port);
        if ($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);            

    /* doesn't */   
    $mysqli_db = new mysqli_db($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database, $db_port);

    ?>
```

Here's the class:

```
<?php
require_once 'IRCinventoryconfig.php';
require("drawTable.inc");
ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);


    class mysqli_db 
    {
        protected $db_hostname;
        protected $db_database;
        protected $db_username;
        protected $db_password;
        protected $db_port;
        protected $connection; 


        function __construct($db_hostname, $db_database, $db_username, $db_password, $db_port)
        {
            $this->db_hostname = $db_hostname;
            $this->db_database = $db_database; 
            $this->db_username = $db_username;
            $this->db_password = $db_password;
            $this->db_port     = $db_port;

            if    (!empty($db_hostname)
                || !empty($db_database)
                || !empty($db_username)
                || !empty($db_password)
                || !empty($db_port))
            {
                $this->_connect();
            } else {
                die("You did not provide enough information, please check your configuration files and try again.");
            }

        }

        public function _connect()
        {
                /* echoes the correct information */
                echo $this->db_hostname;
                echo $this->db_database;
                echo $this->db_username;
                echo $this->db_password;
                echo $this->db_port;

            $this->connection = new mysqli($this->db_hostname, $this->db_username, $this->db_password, $this->db_database, $this->db_port)
            or die("Database access failed:" . $this->connection->error);
            //$this->connection = new mysqli($this->db_hostname, $this->db_username, $this->db_password, $this->db_database, $this->db_port);
            //if ($this->connection->connect_error) die($this->connection->connect_error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your credentials are correct?

Comment: _' Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost''_ is clear enough: your credentials are wrong.  Your `__construct()` method is using `||` where it should be using `&&`, but I don't think that's the cause of this problem.

Comment: I am sure the credentials are correct. All the correct values are echoed and I can connect to the database if I don't use the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments are being provided in the incorrect order to the constructor.

```
$mysqli_db = new mysqli_db($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database, $db_port);

function __construct($db_hostname, $db_database, $db_username, $db_password, $db_port)
```

The constructor should probably look like this:

```
function __construct($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database, $db_port)
```

Answer (score 0):

First all the parameters need to hold a value so:

```
if    (!empty($db_hostname)
            || !empty($db_database)
            || !empty($db_username)
            || !empty($db_password)
            || !empty($db_port))
        {
```

sounds wrong. I'd suggest

```
if    (!empty($db_hostname)
            && !empty($db_database)
            && !empty($db_username)
            && !empty($db_password)
            && !empty($db_port))
        {
```

...and the order of the parameters you pass to the construct is wrong. It must follow the mysqli construct order (host,user,pass,database,port)

Answer (score 0):

That happens if you have done any custom codes (usually).when you transfer the site then it contain info of previous wordpress setup.The info don't match with the site actual login data. So after transferring site do change the info.

in my case it is in function.php

It will look like this :

```
$server="localhost";
    $dbuser="wrdp14";
    $pwd="EIzAT3vu";
    $db="wrdp14";
    $this->conn=new mysqli($server,$dbuser,$pwd,$db);
    if ($this->conn->connect_error)
```

just replace it with your recent wordpress data you can find that in your wp-config file